# Update data from local copy of Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am implementing a user profile edit page that initially consists of the data loaded from the `vuex` store. Then the user can freely edit his data and finally store them in the store.

Since the user can also click the cancel button to revert back to his original state, I decided to create a 'local' view copy of the user data fetched from the store. This data will be held in the view and once the user presses save, they will be saved in the store.

The view looks as following:

```
<template class="user-profile">
  <v-form>
    <template v-if="profile.avatar">
      <div class="text-center">
        <v-avatar width="120" height="120">
          <img
            :src="profile.avatar"
            :alt="profile.firstname"
          >
        </v-avatar>
      </div>
    </template>
    <div class="text-center mt-4">
      <v-btn
        color="primary"
        dark
        @click.stop="showImageDialog=true"
      >
        Change Image
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-text-field
          label="First name"
          single-line
          disabled
          v-model="profile.firstname"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-text-field
          label="Last name"
          single-line
          disabled
          v-model="profile.lastname"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-text-field
      label="Email"
      single-line
      v-model="profile.email"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field
      id="title"
      label="Title"
      single-line
      v-model="profile.title"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-textarea
      no-resize
      clearable
      label="Biography"
      v-model="profile.bio"
    ></v-textarea>
    <v-dialog
      max-width="500"
      v-model="showImageDialog"
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          Update your profile picture
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-file-input @change="setImage" accept="image/*"></v-file-input>
          <template v-if="userAvatarExists">
            <vue-cropper
              ref="cropper"
              :aspect-ratio="16 / 9"
              :src="profile.avatar"
            />
          </template>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            color="green darken-1"
            text
            @click="showImageDialog=false"
          >
            Cancel
          </v-btn>

          <v-btn
            color="green darken-1"
            text
            @click="uploadImage"
          >
            Upload
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <div class="mt-8">
      <v-btn @click="onUpdateUser">Update</v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
  import VueCropper from 'vue-cropperjs';
  import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';

  export default {
    components: { VueCropper},

    mounted() {
      this.profile = this.getUserProfile ? this.getUserProfile : {}
    },
    data() {
      return {
        profile: {},
        avatar: null,
        userAvatarExists: false,
        showImageDialog: false,
      }
    },
    watch: {
      getUserProfile(newData){
        this.profile = newData;
      },
      deep: true
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        getUserProfile: 'user/me',
      })
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        storeAvatar: 'user/storeAvatar',
        updateUser: 'user/update'
      }),
      onUpdateUser() {
        const data = {
          id: this.profile.id,
          email: this.profile.email,
          title: this.profile.title,
          bio: this.profile.bio,
          avatar: this.profile.avatar,
        }
        this.updateUser(data)
      },
      uploadImage() {
        this.$refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob => {
          this.storeAvatar(blob).then((filename => {
            this.profile.avatar = filename.data
            this.$refs.cropper.reset()
          }));
          this.showImageDialog = false
        }));
      },
      setImage(file) {
        this.userAvatarExists = true;
        if (file.type.indexOf('image/') === -1) {
          alert('Please select an image file');
          return;
        }
        if (typeof FileReader === 'function') {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (event) => {
            this.$refs.cropper.replace(event.target.result);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
          alert('Sorry, FileReader API not supported');
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Issues/Questions**:

1. As you can see from the code, after the user changes his profile
   picture, the image should be rendered based on the
   `v-if="profile.avatar"`. The issue is that after the
   `profile.avatar`    is set in the `uploadImage` function, the
   template does not see this    change and no image is rendered.
   However if I change the code so that    the `profile.avatar` becomes
   just `avatar` (it is no longer within the    `profile` object), the
   template starts to see the changes and renders    the image
   correctly. Why so? Does it have something to do with making    a
   copy from the store in the `watch` function?
2. Is it in general a good approach to keep the profile just as a local
   view state or should it rather be stored in the vuex store even if
   it is just a temporary data?
3. As you can see in the `mounted` function, I am setting the `profile`
   value based on the `getUserProfile` getter. This is because the
   `watch` function does not seem to be called again when switching
   routes. Is there any other way how to do this?

Comment: Does 'avatar' prop exist in a profile that you get calling getUserProfile?

Comment: Yes, it does exist there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to the reactivity of data properties

You have used profile as an object, default it doesn't have any properties like avatar or firstname, its just empty

In vue js, If you are declaring an object, whatever the key mention in the declaration is only the part of reactivity. Once the keys inside profile changes, it rerenders the template

But still you can add new properties to a data property object by using $set

lets say in data you have declared 
**profile: {}**

if you want to set avatar as new  reactive property in runtime use

```
this.$set(this.profile, key, value)
```

which is

```
this.$set(this.profile, avatar, imageData)
```

In your above code, **the setIuploadImage function**

```
uploadImage() {
        var self = this;
        self.$refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob => {
          self.storeAvatar(blob).then((filename => {
            self.$set(self.profile, "avatar", filename.data)
            self.$refs.cropper.reset()
          }));
          self.showImageDialog = false
        }));
      },
```

this won't work inside arrow function in vuejs, so just preserved the this inside another  variable "self" and used inside arrow function

Also in mounted function, if **this.getUserProfile returns empty object**, then as per javascript empty object is always truthy and directly assigning object to profile doesn't make the object reactive

```
mounted() {
      this.profile = this.getUserProfile ? this.getUserProfile : {}
    },
```

> above code can be written as

```
mounted() {
  if (this.getUserProfile && Object.keys(this.getUserProfile).length) {
    var self = this;
    Object.keys(this.getUserProfile).map(key => {
      self.$set(self.profile, key, self.getUserProfile[key])
    });
  } else {
    this.profile = {};
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you for the explanation! :) Just last thing, do you think it is a correct place to set the profile when changing routes in the 'mounted' func?

Comment: There are different approaches for update your data. It totally depends on your requirement